# How can I configure my phone for MMS?

Tags: settings, mms

I can not send or receive MMS-messages (containing an image) on my Nexus One phone. And I can't find many settings to set for it.

I have set an adress for APN. But there is also an IP-address, a proxieaddress and a port number that I should set.

How do I set up MMS on Nexus One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need your operator's APN details (hint: ask the operator's customer service or search on Google), which you can enter through `Settings > Tap "Wireless & network settings" > Tap "Mobile networks" > Tap "Access Point Names" > Press "Menu Button" > Tap "New APN"` (eclair/2.1).

Alternatively, many operators can send a special service message that will automatically configure the correct APN settings. You might need to contact your operator's customer service or send an SMS/text message to a special number before they send you the autoconfigure service message.