# Where to find the MMS settings?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-5, mms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure my phone for MMS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/how-can-i-configure-my-phone-for-mms)

I am using a Samsung GT-I5503 and I can't send an mms. Where can I locate the mms settings so that I can configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings >> Wireless & Networks >> Mobile Networks >> Access Point Names

That should list the APNs applicable/configured for your network; Once you select the APN entry (click on the name) you should be able to see/configure MMS.

**Update:** Here is another question on MMS configuration : 
[How can I configure my phone for MMS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/how-can-i-configure-my-phone-for-mms)